# Role of Zookeeper in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper

I understand  based on the slides that in the context of Hadoop that Zookeeper is used for storing information of Master, and status of different tasks, which worker is working on which partition AND also the available workers are also stored in Zookeeper.

Why is Zookeeper is used for this metadata storage here? Any data store can be used right ?

For instance Celery can configure any result backend Redis/Mongo etc. So in practice Hadoop can use any  storage  backend right? But why Zookeeper?

This doc suggests that Redis, SQLite, MySQL, PostgreSQL can be used for celery task result storage.

https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Zookeeper ZAB protocol is utilized for leader election, as well as distributed locks.

It is not simply a datastore, and no, not any can be used.

Celery isn't used within the Hadoop ecosystem, so I'm not sure how that's relevant to the question.

Comment: Thanks for your response and explaining the features of Zookeeper. That doesn't still address my question. Can we not keep the statuses of Master, different mappers and reducers tasks in any datastore. Precisely, what difference does ZAB protocol make especially in the context of achieving our goal ?   And also, regarding Celery: I just wanted to bring an analogy. Celery also wants to maintain the statuses of tasks and uses general data stores.

Comment: No, you cannot. Hadoop is primarily Java based, as is Zookeeper. There is no Celery Java driver, from what I can tell. There was once a ticket for maintaining Hive Metastore in Cassandra rather than an RDBMS, but that was abandoned. The only other alternative to Zookeeper is some Raft-based solution (e.g. Apache Ratis), but Hadoop has been around for over a decade, and everyone has accepted that Zookeeper does a good enough job, and there is no abstraction layer around it for leader-election in the Hadoop source code, AFAIK.